# Optimize Postgres \Copy from csv to a table in terms of performance

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a csv file with 10 million rows and I'm try to import it in a postgres table

Is importing one huge file at once in a database same as importing multiple chunks files in terms of speed and performance ?

Is `COPY` statement the best way to import a huge file in a database ?

Comment: Maybe using python pandas and comparing times.

Comment: If you use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) then use the `\timing` meta-command. Yes `COPY` or the `psql` equivalent `\copy` is the best way to import large amounts of data. There is one caveat though both commands are all or nothing, either the entire statement succeeds or a single error will roll back the whole thing.